# Extract string between the tags in Java

Tags: java, string, parsing, text-extraction

I have string like below

```
Msg_Begin
Some message1
Msg_End
Msg_Begin
Some message2
Msg_End
Msg_Begin
Some message3
Msg_End
```

And want to get the message between **Msg_Begin** and **Msg_End** in to the list 
like

`[Some message1, Some message2, Some message3]`

what is the best approach for this in Java.

Comment: what approach you think?

Comment: I know to extract string between two strings using the index and substring method. But I couldnt think any easy approach to loop and extrat strings. I dont want to use regular expression since I am very poor in those concepts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```java
var messages = originalString.replaceAll("Msg_Begin", "");
var array = messages.split("Msg_End");
return Arrays.asList(array);
```

Just make sure that your messages do not contain `Msg_Begin` or `Msg_End`.

Comment: what if a message contains a `\n`?

Comment: you can actually try that too before asking. Simply put break string and see what is gonna happen. If you dont want to delete break string than change your code accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve that with a regular expression :

```
//Filling Your test case and print
String entry = "Msg_Begin\r\n" + 
               "Some message1\r\n" + 
               "Msg_End\r\n" + 
               "Msg_Begin\r\n" + 
               "Some message2\r\n" + 
               "Msg_End\r\n" + 
               "Msg_Begin\r\n" + 
               "Some message3\r\n" + 
               "Msg_End";

System.out.println("IN : \r\n" + entry) ;

//Compile the regular expression patern, providing the DOTALL flag to enable mutiline matches
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Msg_Begin\r\n(.+?)\r\nMsg_End(\r\n)?", Pattern.DOTALL) ;  
Matcher m = p.matcher(entry) ; 

// iterate over results (for exemple add them to a list)
System.out.println("\r\nOUT :") ;
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
while (m.find()) {
    list.add( m.group(1));
    System.out.println(m.group(1)) ;
}
```

Produce the following result :

```
IN : 
Msg_Begin
Some message1
Msg_End
Msg_Begin
Some message2
Msg_End
Msg_Begin
Some message3
Msg_End

OUT :
Some message1
Some message2
Some message3
```

More informations abour regular expressions syntax can be found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/index.html)